# Сделать текст бегущей строкой при наведении

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть менюшка. `table-cell`. Состоит из 8 пунктов. По размеру все одинаковые `width: calc(100% / 8);`. В последнем пункте меню, не 1 слово как во всех,а 2. И по этому текст переходит на вторую строку, и под другими пунктами создается пустое пространство.По этому думаю сделать последнему пункту меню `overflow: hidden`. А при наведении, что б текст двигался как бегущая строка. Как это можно сделать? или есть еще какое то решение?

Comment: Пример анимации текста с бегущей строкой есть?

Comment: нет. Ну стандартно, что б текст с права на лево двигался

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вроде бы так**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  width: 100px;
  height: 22px;
  line-height: 22px;
  margin: 5px 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
li a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 350px;
}
li:hover a {
  animation: trey 5s infinite;
}
@keyframes trey {
  100%{
    margin-left: -300%;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="">Длинное меню из четырёх слов</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">Очень длинное меню которое длинее предыдущего</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Я бы заменил `from` на `100%`. Всё-таки мы читаем слева-направо

Comment: исправил пример

Answer (score 2):

Другой вариант, с `translateX`

```css
.menuItem {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
.menuItem span {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: 3s;
}
.menuItem:hover span {
  transform: translateX(calc(100px - 100%));
}
```

```html
<div class="menuItem">
  <span>
    Пример очень длинного описания пункта меню
  </span>
</div>
<div class="menuItem">
  <span>
    Другой пример очень длинного описания пункта меню
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо. Возьму на заметку!)